# Exception 'android.system.ErrnoException' occurred in thread 'SharedPreferencesImpl-load' at libcore.io.Linux.access(Linux.java:-1)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to work through building the google sunflower app and I am getting stuck loading my json file I think. I am unable to  hit any break points which to me means that I am breaking on an error loading permissions maybe. I am debugging on an actual pizel 3 and I think perhaps I have my phone locked down too much. I have also tried adding reading permissions to the manifest file. Here is the code

```
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        // create the room
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
            .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                // when created, seed it
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    // create the work manager request
                    val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SeedDatabaseWorker>().build()
                    // fire it
                    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
                }
            })
            .build()
         }
```

and here is my error stack from debugging:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8608', transport: 'socket'
Exception 'android.system.ErrnoException' occurred in thread 'SharedPreferencesImpl-load' at libcore.io.Linux.access(Linux.java:-1)
Breakpoint reached
      at libcore.io.Linux.access(Linux.java:-1)
      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:73)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:71)
      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:73)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:7246)
      at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
      at java.io.File.exists(File.java:815)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:136)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:55)
      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:126)
Exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' occurred in thread 'main' at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java:-1)
Breakpoint reached
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java:-1)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1358)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1418)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:776)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2084)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2627)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2694)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2094)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:575)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
      at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
      at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
      at com.stegner.androiddex.PokedexActivity.onCreate(PokedexActivity.kt:22)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8608', transport: 'socket'
```

I am only able to hit this when I toggle Java exception and exception breakpoints. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a rather odd way of saying "there is an incorrect tag in your layout XML".

Comment: Correct! I couldn't find the exact tag causing the problem bit I went one by one deleting them and fixed the problem thanks!